# Простой вывод данных в Java

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени суток господа. (Делаю в Java первые шаги)

Структура проекта:

```
+ xfx (пакет)
  + one (пакет)
    - li1 (класс)
    - li2 (класс)
    - li3 (класс)
    - Main (класс)
    - li5 (класс)
  + two (пакет)
    - Main (класс)
```

xfx.one -> пустой, как и все остальные классы, если написать System.out.println("123"); - выведет

xfx.two -> если написать System.out.println("123"); - компилиться, но ничего не выводит

```
//содержимое - xfx.two
package xfx.two;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("123");
    }
}
```

В много численных лекциях из инета - все работает, сам никак не могу понять, почему у меня в xfx.two - System.out.println не выполняется. Может кто сказать, как исправить?

p.s. проект тестовый. Знаю, названия классов и пакетов так же красотой не отличаются

Comment: в чём компилите? как запускаете?

Comment: Интел идея, сохраняю и кнопка Run

Comment: Лишь один `main` метод будет являться `entry point` для приложения. А какой именно из ваших двух — смотрите в настройках `run configuration` в IDEA (опция `Main class`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверьте как вы стартуете ваши main в вашем IDE. Вполне возможно, что вы не сохранили ваши классы. Возможно просто не то запускаете. Вариантов масса.

Comment: ..мм сохранил, для надежности закрыл IDE, и открыл снова, весь код на месте, работает так же (

Comment: проверьте внимательно. вы в ide стартуете не тот main метод.

Comment: как запускать проекты в idea  http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-applications.html

Comment: Запустил, сработало все, спс!

Answer (score 3):

вы запускаете один и тот же класс.

вам надо создать ещё одну конфигурацию для запуска:

Run->Edit Configurations->откроется вот такое окно [image: скрин_1]

В нём

1. добавляем новую конфигурацию для
   java
2. указываете класс для запуска
3. указываем что перед запуском его
   нужно откомпилировать
4. не забываем указать имя...

теперь в списке запуска есть новый класс...

[image: скрин_2]

p.s. есть и более быстрый способ

[image: скрин_3]

Comment: Вот теперь полностью дошло